# Why does My Viewport show pixels?

Tags: 3d-view

[image][image: screenshot of pixels in 3d viewport]
Please see the screenshots.  My Viewport is showing pixels. this has never happened before.  The pixels come on and off.  My display unit is fine because it only happens when I open blender.  I am using a dell Inspiron with NVidia 640M graphics.

The only new program I installed is Skype which I installed yesterday

The pixels show up while editing.  Need help

Thabani

Comment: Welcome to BSE. Does this happen in other applications or games too or is it only visible in Blender?

Comment: ok forget my first comment partially, you stated that Blender was then only application showing this. However, is this the first time you installed Blender on this specific machine? Or did it start from one day to the other?

Comment: Hi, aliasguru.  It only happens in blender.  no problems with other applications.    I've used Blender on this PC for two months without any issues but all of a sudden the pixels started showing up today.

Comment: very strange. I was asking only because the whole User Interface of Blender is being drawn in OpenGL, so other Applications which do the same should suffer from the same issue. For the moment I have no clue what's causing this...

Comment: Re-install the drivers for the GPU. Also make sure that the program you just installed is not running while using blender.

Comment: Thanks, cegaton.  that worked.  reinstalling the drivers worked